# Ajax submit to self PHP file, but seems the PHP function do not execute

Tags: php, html, ajax

Ajax submit to self PHP file, but seems the PHP function do not execute.

```
<?php

function request(){
    echo "<h1>requested</h1>";
}

?>
<html id="html">
<button id="btn_click" onclick="request1()">click</button>


</html>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function request1(){
        document.write("<h1>been clicked</h1>");
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/index.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

The JavaScript execute success, but seems the PHP code did not execute.

Comment: The PHP function `request` is never called. (That also assume the JS sends correctly, I use jquery for ajax interactions)

Comment: Please call request(); php function!.

Comment: Working example please check the PHP fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xfc2-wg1c

Comment: @RajaRamaMohanThavalam Should probably only call `request()` if the request is an ajax request. Also doesn't appear to do anything with the ajax response, or i cant read vanilla js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what `gibberish` said, however, there's more to it. You must also keep in mind you don't seem to be executing the function at all.

A PHP function does nothing unless it is called.

```
function request() {
  echo "<h1>Hello</h1>"
}
```

The function above will not be affected unless you call it:

```
request() // <h1>Hello</h1>
```

---

Also AJAX is best used when keeping requests simple. You send a request `/path/to/file.php` then that requests should return a plain text response or a JSON object, or a fully rendered static page if you are using a modal or some static item on your site.

/path/to/file.php

```
<?php

if( $_GET['clicked'] ) {

  // do whatever 

  echo json_encode([
    'user_id' => 1,
    'total_clicks' => $_GET['clicked'],
    'random_number' => rand(100, 999)
  ]);

}
```

The JS can easily handle the response:

```
function request(id) {
  return fetch(`/path/to/file.php?clicked=${id}`)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            body.innerHTML += res.user_id;
            body.innerHTML += res.total_clicks;
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

This will be the simplest way to have your server return information from the DB and make your page content as interactive as you need it to be,.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` help us to detect an AJAX request

```
    <?php
//Check Here Ajax Request
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
    function request(){
       echo "<h1>requested</h1>";
    }
    request();
    die;
}
?>
<html id="html">
    <body>
        <button id="btn_click" onclick="request1()">click</button>
        <div class="response" id="result" ></div>

        <script  type="text/javascript">
            function request1(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
                       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                       }
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "./index.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // <-- ADD this
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```